# Access and deploy problems with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku, ssh, ssh-keys

I've been using Heroku normally in the past few months. In the beginning, I created a ssh key, I added it to my Heroku account and I could deploy my apps without any problem. Until today. I'm working on a new project and I needed to create a new Heroku account under a different e-mail address. After a while I realized I couldn't deploy this app using a new e-mail address because my SSH key was associated to a different e-mail. Then I created a new SSH key and added it to my new Heroku account. It didn't work! :)

Well, I removed the key from my computer and from my new Heroku account. Then I decided to go back to my original Heroku account. Everything works, well, more or less. I can still deploy my old apps, I can see I only have one SSH key there, I can run the commands: `heroku info`, `heroku apps`, etc.

So then I tried to deploy my new app, but before I created a new Heroku app using: `heroku create`. The new app was created successfully. But when I try: `git push heroku` I get this error:

> !  Your key with fingerprint
>   b2:69:3b:90:1e:e1:60:ad:a0:b9:f7:**:**:**:** is not authorized to
>   access furious-leaf-9996.

If I try: `heroku info`, I get this error:

> !    You do not have access to
>   furious-leaf-9996.

The funny thing is, if I switch to the other app's directory and try to do the same thing (ex.: `heroku info`, `git push heroku`), everything works perfectly.

Note 1: When I try `heroku logout` then `heroku login`, I'm always able to connect, in both app's directory

Note 2: I'm using RVM and both apps use different gemsets.

I don't know what else to do!! Anyone??

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After getting almost crazy I found out what was happening.

When I first tried to login on my second Heroku account, my .git config file was updated with this info:

```
[remote "heroku"]
url = git@heroku.com:furious-leaf-9996.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

And this was the problem. Even logging out and logging in again in different Heroku accounts, every time I tried to push my files there, I couldn't because I didn't have access to this repository. And it got worse because I deleted this repository. :)

Now everything is working properly.

So next time you have access problems on Heroku, take a look at your git config file!

Thanks!